# Parquet Conversion from CSV dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, parquet

Can't get it to perform the conversion

```
data['date']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%Y%m%d')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_parquet('data.gzip', compression='gzip')
```

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_parquet'

Comment: It's not pyspark, it's pandas isn't it? Please fix tags.

Comment: What is your pandas version ?
Your code should work if the version is >= 0.21.0